# Why the query returns more than one result?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have four SQL Server database tables:

1. `inventory`
2. `inventory2`
3. `bdo`
4. `details`

Structure is as:

**inventory**

```
AllocationID   MSISDN
1              3018440225
2              3028431115
```

**Inventory2**

```
    AllocationID   MSISDN
    1              3011234567
    2              3026440657
    3              3454159650
```

**BDO**

```
BDO_ID      BDO_MSISDN
1           3457076952
2           3005000475
```

**Details**

```
AllocationID    MSISDN
3               3454159650
```

Now I need to get the records from following query:

```
select a.msisdn, b.bdo_id
from details a, bdo b, inventory c, inventory2 d
where 
    a.msisdn = 3454159650
    and (a.allocationid = c.allocationid) or (a.allocationid = d.allocationid)
    and (c.bdo_id = b.bdo_id) or (d.bdo_id = b.bdo_id)
```

This query returns more than 1 result (all exactly same) why is it so??? if I am wrong please correct my concepts and query.

Comment: You should add parenthesis in your where clause. I don't think the current conditions result in what you expect them to be. Why are you not using joins?

Comment: @PatrickKostjens it looks like he's doing that instead of outer joins, but it's hard to really know.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: @Rahul: this is for **SQL Server** - and T-SQL doesn't have `LIMIT` (that's a MySQL-specific method)

Comment: Also, I find it positive you're using table aliases - but I would pick **more intuitive** aliases than just `a, b, c, d` - use `details d`, `inventory i`, `inventory2 i2` - those will be **much easier** to read and understand!

Comment: What is the exact relation between your tables? What are the foreign keys? Your query suggests there's a field `bdo_id` in inventory but I don't see it in the structure you post above.

Answer (score 2):

You have a very strange form for the query.  First, you should use `join` syntax.  Second, you seem to want a union between the two inventory tables:

```
select d.msisdn, b.bdo_id
from (select i.*
      from (select i.* from inventory i union all
            select i2.* from inventory i2
           ) i
     ) i join
     details d
     on d.allocationid = i.allocationid join
     bdo b
     on i.bdo_id=b.bdo_id
where d.msisdn = 3454159650;
```

Structuring the query as explicit joins should make it more efficient and should make it easier to understand, get correct, and maintain.

EDIT:

It is possible that you are missing some records in some tables.  Try using this version with a `left outer join`:

```
select d.msisdn, b.bdo_id
from details d left outer join
     (select i.*
      from (select i.* from inventory i union all
            select i2.* from inventory i2
           ) i
     ) i
     details d
     on d.allocationid = i.allocationid left outer join
     bdo b
     on i.bdo_id=b.bdo_id
where d.msisdn = 3454159650;
```

Comment: this gives no result, all I want is that if the allocation ID exists in wither inventory or inventory2 there should be some result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised it returns anything. You're referring to a bdo_id field that doesn't exist.

Your main problem is the priority of `and` over `or`

Try this instead

```
select a.msisdn,b.bdo_id
from details a,bdo b,inventory c,inventory2 d
where 
a.msisdn=3454159650
and ((a.allocationid = c.allocationid) or (a.allocationid = d.allocationid))
and ((c.bdo_id=b.bdo_id) or (d.bdo_id=b.bdo_id))
```

Comment: still same results... :(

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not return value. This query raise error. 
Last row of your query this

```
and (c.bdo_id = b.bdo_id) or (d.bdo_id = b.bdo_id)
```

C is your inventory table and inventory table has no column name with bdo_id

and

D is your inventory2 table and inventory2 table has no column name with bdo_id